Angular test case failing after angular upgrade 7 to 14
  it('should return true if not in preview mode', () => {
  expect(component.isInPreviewCloud(false, <PortfolioStrategy>{})).toBeTruthy();
});

is throwing error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isInPreviewCloud')
